# Message Enricher Usage

Tags: esb, mule

I have a mule flow with some javabean payload, what i'd like to do is enrich some varaiables using some xml (xpath) returned from an https outbound url.

What i"m trying is something like: (Assume the whole certificate/tls issue is not the problem):

```
<enricher>
    <https:outbound-endpoint name="clientEndpoint" address="https://someaddress" 
         connector-ref="httpConnector" exchange-pattern="request-response"/> 
        <enrich target="#[variable:paymentValidated]" source="#[xpath:INCIDENTS/INCIDENT/@state]" />
</enricher>
<logger message="#[variable:paymentValidated]" level="ERROR" />
```

However, i cant seem to be able to work with the xml returned from the https endpoint, i keep getting XPATH violations. after checking my xpath with a validator i am certain that i am giving a correct xpath.

I also tried using a bytearraytostring response tranformer - but the problem was not solved.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this and make it work??

The xml i"m attempting to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<INCIDENTS process_ms="56">
  <INCIDENT assignee="Unassigned" closedtime="" createdtime="Fri Jan 20 15:13:10 EST 2012" creator="System" disposition="Not Set" disposition_id="-1" domain="SES" guid="5749976847410062927" id="147" incident_type="security" modifiedtime="Sat Jan 21 15:13:15 EST 2012" open_duration="2 days 18 hours 53 mins 56 secs" priority="3" referencenum="0000000147" severity="4" state="New" state_id="0" status="Open" status_id="1" team="Unassigned" tracking="No" type="SomeType" userpriority="">
    <DESCRIPTION>
    <![CDATA[ Some message" ]]> 
    </DESCRIPTION>
  </INCIDENT>
</INCIDENTS>
```

Comment: Can you show the root cause in the error stack you're getting? Also, is the XML source in any namespace? The XPath you use assume no namespace.

Comment: I dont have it infront of me   but ot was could not evaluate xpath . Not following your point regarding the namespace im afraid

Comment: Can you show an example of the XML message you want to use Xpath on? We'll immediately know if it's in any namespace. If that is the case, you'll need to configure the namespace manager otherwise it will never work.

Comment: Thanks, no namespace in play here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not showing the exact error, I'll try to guess.

I think the issue comes from the fact you select the state attribute from a list of incidents instead of just one. Try with:

```
/INCIDENTS/INCIDENT[1]/@state
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the feature of Mule Xpath3 which is from Mule 3.6
Something like follow :-

```
#[xpath3('/INCIDENTS/INCIDENT[1]/@state')]
```

Please find the linke for Xpath3 here :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XPath